# DbContext - Many to Many reliationship between three tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Well i've been tring for some time to make Many-to-Many relationship between three tables.
Forum, Role, AccessMask.
In SQL It would like this:

```
ForumID | RoleID | AccessMaskID
--------------------------------
1       | 1      | 2
2       | 2      | 1
```

And so on. You got the idea. ForumID and RoleID is primary key for table. Question is.. how to do it in DbContext ?
It alawys screaming that entity is missing key. (really ?). I found a way to make and many-to-many relationship between two tables with modelBuilder, but as you see I still will be missing one more table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not be many-to-many relationship. You must expose this table as separate entity and map three one-to-many relationships. Many-to-many relationship works only between two tables if junction table contains only keys of these tables.

```
public class Forum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ForumRole> ForumRoles { get; set; } 
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ForumRole> ForumRoles { get; set; } 
}

public class AccessMask
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ForumRole> ForumRoles { get; set; } 
}

public class ForumRole
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int AccessMaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual AccessMask AccssMask { get; set; }
}
```